# Multiple series of endnotes not working on different places

Tags: eledmac

i try to edit two seperate books in one volume. The corrections to the text should follow immediately after the text, the notes for all books at the very end.
Unfortunately this MWE is not working, the comments of the endnotes B are missing:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\part{Book one}

\chapter{The Text of book one}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
A \edtext{complicated word}{\Bendnote{Explanation from book 1}} Blablabla \edtext{wrong}{\Aendnote{worng}} word
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{The corrections to the text of book one}
\doendnotes{A}

\part{Book two}

\chapter{The Text of book two}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Another \edtext{not so clear}{\Cendnote{Explanation from book 1}} Blablabla and a \edtext{misspelled}{\Aendnote{imsspelled}} word
\pend
\endnumbering

\part{Notes on all works}

\section{Book 1}
\doendnotes{B}

\section{Book 2}
\doendnotes{C}

\end{document}
```

What do i do wrong? I read the manual, but the \doendnotesbysection{} command is not helping me either-

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: it seems to be a bug. I am looking for it https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/348

Comment: yes, it's a bug. I will take a quite long time to correct it. I think to do it tonight.

Comment: I have noted what I must do. https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/348#issuecomment-121957529. That will be tonight code.

Comment: I have corrected it in a dev branch. I have asked you on github to test this (althought my tests are positif).

Comment: thank you! as i wrote over there, your correction works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was effectivly a bug. It has been corrected in reledmac, the sucessor of eledmac, which I have just uploaded on CTAN.

Note that this new version, in order to correct this bug, produce one files by series of endnotes. So in order to save room for \write, use the series argument of the package, to create only series you need.